# AnyDAC - TADConnection attribute FCommands contains released objects

Tags: delphi, exception, disconnect, bde, anydac

At the moment we are migrating the database component of our **Delphi7** application from the **BDE** components to **AnyDAC Version 8.0.5** components (in the meantime known as FireDAC).

We are using the following controls in our MDI child form:

- `TADTable`
- `TDataSource`
- `TDBNavigator`
- `TDBEdit` (a `TStringField` is assigned to the `DataField` property)
- `TDBMemo` (a `TMemoField` is assigned to the DataField property [`DB Field Type = Blob`])

all database controls are connected to each other

When we change two or three records, we'll receive an `EAccessViolation` during the disconnect of the `TADCustomConnection`.
The `EAccessViolation` appears in the following method of the `TCustomConnection` (inside unit `DB`):

```
procedure TCustomConnection.SendConnectEvent(Connecting: Boolean);
var
  I: Integer;
  ConnectEvent: TConnectChangeEvent;
begin
  for I := 0 to FClients.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if FConnectEvents[I] <> nil then
    begin
      TMethod(ConnectEvent).Code := FConnectEvents[I];
      TMethod(ConnectEvent).Data := FClients[I];
      ConnectEvent(Self, Connecting);
    end;
    if TObject(FClients[I]) is TDataset then  // <-- raises the EAccessViolation
      TDataSet(FClients[I]).DataEvent(deConnectChange, Integer(Connecting));
  end;
end;
```

Reason for this `EAccessViolation` is the fact that the `TADCustomConnection.FCommands` attribute contains released `TADCommands`.
Normally everything works like a charm, but if we exclude `fiBlobs` in the `TADTable.FetchOption.Items` or if we just execute the `RefreshRecord` method in the event `TADTable.BeforeEdit` we receive the `EAccessViolation`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.